# solving diophantine problem $a^3+b^3=2019(1+ab)$ for coprime $a$ and $b$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, diophantine-equations

We're interested in solving

$$\begin{cases} a^3+b^3=2019(1+ab) \\ \gcd(a,b)=1 \end{cases}$$

I'm stuck with the deduction

1. Say why $a^3 \equiv -b^3 \pmod{2019}$ . **(done)**
2. Using Fermat, prove that $a^{672} \equiv b^{672} \pmod{2019}$ . **(done)**
3. Deduce that $a \equiv -b \pmod{2019}$ (note that $673 = 1 + 244*3$) **(stuck)**

thanks for any help.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I'm guessing OP wants help with the part where it says "stuck".

Comment: @ahmed Note $37^3 + (-13)^3 = 48\text{,}456 = 24(2019)$, with $\gcd(37,-13) = 1$. This shows you can't deduce $a \equiv -b \pmod{2019}$ strictly from $a^3 \equiv -b^3 \pmod{2019}$. However, my example doesn't satisfy the requirement of $a^3+b^3=2019(1+ab)$, so perhaps this also needs to be used to get your third deduction, but I don't offhand see how.

Comment: It looks like all solutions $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ with $a\leq b$ are $(-1,1)$ and $(1009,1010)$.  So far, I could only prove that $a\equiv -b\pmod{2019}$, $a\equiv929b\pmod{2019}$, or $a\equiv-928b\pmod{2019}$.

Comment: 2). Comes from 1). I don't see why you need Fermat here. So it feels useless

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method that will work, though you'll need a computer like [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to do the computations... unless you really want to do it by hand, which is also doable.

The idea is to use the factorization $$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx).$$ Luckily, $$2019 = 3\cdot 673,$$ where the factor of $3$ is exceedingly important for the applicability of this technique. Then the equation $$a^3+b^3=2019(1+ab)$$ can be rewritten as $$a^3 + b^3+673^3 - 3ab\cdot 673 =3\cdot 673 +673^3$$ or equivalently $$(a+b+673)(a^2+b^2+673^2-ab-673a-673b)=2^2\cdot 673\cdot 113233.$$ The rest is easy, albeit computationally intensive. The number of positive divisors of the right side is $$(2+1)(1+1)(1+1)=12,$$ so there are $24$ ordered pairs of integers $(s,t)$ that can multiply to the right side, since we have to account for negative factors. So set the $a+b+673$ equal to each possible factor $s,$ isolate $b$ and substitute it into $$a^2+b^2+673^2-ab-673a-673b=t.$$ That will give you a quadratic in $a$ that you can solve using the quadratic formula. If you get an integer, find the corresponding $b$ using $b=s-a-673.$ Good luck with the details.

Comment: You might not need to use a computer at all (except, possibly, to check that $113233$ is prime).  It can be easily seen that $$|a+b|=2019\frac{|1+ab|}{a^2-ab+b^2}\leq 2019\,.$$  Your result shows that $a+b+673$ is positive.  Therefore, $$0<a+b+673\leq 2019+673=2^2\cdot 673\,.$$  Now, there are very few divisors of $2^2\cdot 673\cdot 113233$ that are smaller than $2^2\cdot 673$.  I don't have any votes left to give you today, so if I don't forget, I will upvote your answer tomorrow.  (If you would like to, please feel free to incorporate my comment into your answer.)

Comment: Note also that $a+b$ must be divisible by $3$, which further lowers the number of cases we have to deal with.  (There will be only $4$ cases, I think.)

Comment: @Batominovski, nice work. Your comment already explains well how to reduce the casework, so I'll leave my answer as is. Thanks for looking into how the computation can be done by hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple but not elementary method.
$$a^3+b^3=2019(1+ab)\tag{1}$$
Let $s=a+b$ and substitute $b=s-a$ to equation $(1)$, then we get

$(3s+2019)a^2+(-3s^2-2019s)a+s^3-2019=0\tag{2}$

In order to quadratic equation for $a$ has rational solution, the discriminant must be a rational number.

$v^2 = -3s^4+4038s^3+4076361s^2+24228s+16305444$

So, above quartic equation must have integral solutions.

Using online Magma calculator as follows.

IntegralQuarticPoints($[-3,4038,4076361,24228,16305444]$);

It says that all integral points are $[[-673, 0 ], [ 0, 4038 ], [ 2019, 8076 ]]$.

Hence all integral solutions are $(a,b)=(1,-1),(-1,1),(1010, 1009),(1009, 1010).$